# AWS Beanstalk Worker - Node.js Message format

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm in a place I get to too often with AWS. I'm figuring out how to use the worker app in Elastic Beanstalk. I have an express app set up to listen to a post. I put a message into my SQL queue. I get something in node, as I can trigger a message. But I have not idea how to get at the payload. As usual, I seem to be left grasping with AWS trying to glean the most basic of details from the documentation. If anyone can give me any pointers, I would much appreciate it. I'm basically just pasting some JSON into the message body on the AWS SQS console at this point in time. I have tried request.body and request.payload on the Node side - nothing.

This is the request that gets hit when the data comes - it's pretty simply. Should put into log. I've tried request.body, request.params, I get 'undefined'. I dumped out the entire request object here, and I'm not seeing it. As I don't know where it's supposed to be, I can't even tell whether it's my code, or it's just not there.

```
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

function test(request, response, next)
{

    mainLog.log("info",stringify(request));

    respond_to_HTTP_request(response, null, null);;
}
exports.test = test;
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to handle SQS messages?

Comment: I'm not. Unless I'm completely confused, you set up an HTTP end point, using something like Express. There is a config settting in Beanstalk where you indicate what that local end point is. So, if I'm not understanding that correctly, and I have to set it up to handle an SQS message, that would be my problem. But that's not what the documentation seems to indicate.

Comment: No, you understand correctly.  Would you please share the code you are using to handle the HTTP posts coming from the sqsd utility that pulls messages from the SQS queue?

Comment: Added the function that deals with the code. The main server.js file and additional functions would be a bit much.

Comment: Essentialy, it's just an express app. We have a REST API set up.

Comment: Sigh. Forgot to add bodyparser to Express. Arg. Now works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Setup and configure the body-parser module:

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

then your payload will be available within your function:

`var payload = request.body;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of how this code answers the question will improve your answer for future visitors (this answer was flagged as low-quality).